# Making POST request to web serivce

Tags: php, http, post

Simply put, I need to make a POST request to a web service using a php script. The problem is that the php version on the server is 4.4.x and curl is disabled. Any ideas how I can make the call and read the response?

Comment: If only that was an option :(

Comment: Out of my hands. Welcome to the corporate world :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fopen`](http://www.php.net/fopen) and [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php), as per the example on the `stream_context_create` page:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array (
        'method' => 'GET'
    )
));
$fp = fopen ('http://www.example.com', 'r', $context);
$text = '';
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $text .= fread($fp, 8192);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Also, see [HTTP context options](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) and [Socket context options](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/context.socket.php) to see the options you can set.

Answer (score 1):

you could basically use socket (fsockopen) and fputs like this :

```
$port = 80;
$server = "domain.com";
$valuesInPost = 'param=value&ahah=ohoho';
$lengthOfThePost = strlen($valuesInPost);

if($fsock = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr)){
    fputs($fsock, "POST /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1 \r\n");
    fputs($fsock,"Host: $server \r\n");
    fputs($fsock,"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13 \r\n");
    fputs($fsock,"Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 \r\n");
    fputs($fsock,"Keep-Alive: 115 \r\n");
    fputs($fsock,"Connection: keep-alive\r\n");
    fputs($fsock,"Referer: http://refererYou.want\r\n");
    fputs($fsock,"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    fputs($fsock,"Content-Length: $lengthOfThePost\r\n\r\n");
    fputs($fsock,"$valuesInPost\r\n\r\n");
    $pcontent = "";

    // results
    while (!feof($fsock))
        $pcontent .= fgets($fsock, 1024);

   // echoes response
   echo $pcontent;
}
```

There might be some syntax errors due to like rewriting.

Note you can use the port you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to PEAR http_request?